# Secure page not displaying inside iframe in internet explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe

Our secure finance form is embedded in a third parties website using an iframe. The form displays correctly in Chrome and Firefox but does not in Internet Explorer. I have tested on IE 11, IE 10, and IE 9. In Internet explorer, instead of the form, inside the iframe the homepage loads.

Is this an Internet Explorer issue or is there anything we can do?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include `http://` in the `src` field as this is a common mistake that causes that issue.

Like this:

```
<iframe width="300" height="3000" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/something..." frameborder="0"</iframe>
```

Make sure you have `ActiveX` and `Scripting` turned on on your IE settings.

Comment: So the issue is not related to that, at least there is something else. Can you please post more info? Include the code for the iframe and maybe some images of the correct and the wrong output. That will help a lot so we can post you the correct answer for your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In IE, the parent page and the iFrame need to use the same protocol. So for this to work you need to ensure both use HTTPS.